# AndroidJNIClass unable to excute my non-static function

Tags: android, java-native-interface, unity-game-engine

i have calling java function from my unity code.
I have both static & non-static type of functions in my java class
**To access first static function**, i used:

```
AndroidJavaClass plugin = new AndroidJavaClass("com.android.test.TestActivity");
AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");        
plugin.CallStatic("InstantiateMe", qwe);
```

above code is running fine, but after this , when i m trying to execute my non static function, its not actually executing.. Not even giving any exception or error..

**My code to call non-static function**

```
AndroidJavaClass plugin = new AndroidJavaClass("com.android.test.TestActivity");
AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");        
plugin.Call("Enable", qwe);
```

Help me guyz. i stucked here.

Comment: can you please post your solution here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use your "activity" variable for non-static calls: `activity.Call("Enable", qwe);`
There is example of static and non-static functions calls:

```
public class Caller {
  private readonly AndroidJavaClass _ActivityClass;
  private readonly AndroidJavaObject _ActivityObject;
  private readonly AndroidJavaClass _MyActivityClass; 

  public Caller() {
    _ActivityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    _MyActivityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.example.u2aTest.MyMainActivity"); 

    _ActivityObject = _ActivityClass.GetStatic("currentActivity");
    // AndroidJavaObject my_activity_object = _MyActivityClass.GetStatic("currentActivity"); //doesn't work
  }

  public void MakeTestCalls() {
    _ActivityObject.Call("testVoid"); // works fine
    //_ActivityClass.CallStatic("testVoidStatic"); // doesn't works
   _MyActivityClass.CallStatic("testVoidStatic"); // works fine
    //_ActivityObject.CallStatic("testVoid"); // doesn't work on some divices

   //public int testInt(int intValue)
   int iresult = _ActivityObject.Call<int>("testInt", 999);

   //public String testStringString(String paramValue)
   String sresult = _ActivityObject.Call<String>("testStringString", "s2");      

   //public static int testIntStatic(int intValue) 
   iresult = _MyActivityClass.CallStatic<int>("testIntStatic", 999);

   //public static String testStringStringStatic(String paramValue)
   sresult =_MyActivityClass.CallStatic<String>("testStringStringStatic", "s1");
  }
}
```

Take a look on [example of Android plugin for Unity3D](http://code.google.com/p/dvsrc/downloads/detail?name=20121113_Unity2AndroidTest.7z) for detailes.

Comment: Thankx man. But i managed it in other way. But i marked your answer