# How to Call a non-static void method of java in Unity3d?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

i want to call a non-static void method of java from Unity.

I read the answer at ( [Unity3d integration with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749841/unity3d-integration-with-android)).

In this What is "currentActivity" ? am getting an error "no static field with name='currentActivity' ...." etc

code :

```
AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"); 
AndroidJavaObject activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
```

Is UnityPlayer is a class in Java ? What is "currentActivity" ?

Answer (score 1):

"CurrentActivity" might be the public static class name where your java function is declared.